# Load text from a file in a QRC file in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I’m trying to load some text to TextArea from a file in QRC. But I don't know how to do that. [QML file](https://github.com/ChungZH/cutenp/blob/master/src/AboutWindow.qml) [QRC file](https://github.com/ChungZH/cutenp/blob/master/resources.qrc)

---

I tried to do that in C++, too. Code:

```cpp
QFile file(":/assets/CREDIT.md");
```

But I just get an error: `QIODevice::read (QFile, ":\assets\CREDIT.md"): device not open` [Cpp file](https://github.com/ChungZH/cutenp/blob/master/src/aboutwindowBackend.hpp#L31)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is clear, you have to open the file:

```cpp
QFile file(":/assets/CREDIT.md");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return;
```