# Setting Text from QRC in QML TextArea

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have a Qt Quick QML file with a `TextArea` that I would like have display text from a QRC resource. Other controls with images have a `source` member that can be set to load directly from a QRC QURL (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69311344/how-to-use-qrc-files-in-qml-files)) but TextArea must set the text directly. What is the most concise way in Qt 5.x to set the text value from a QRC resource? I would like

```
        TextArea
        {
            text: LoadResource("qrc://messages.txt")
        }
```

Another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448728/load-text-from-a-file-in-a-qrc-file-in-qml) alludes to a simple process but the code is gone and now only shows how to use do it in C++.

Comment: As I know the QML/Javascript has no file IO functions. You probably have to write a custom C++ loader, fortunately, it's quite simple, a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest` to access local file and embedded resources but it requires `QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ` environment variable set to 1, e.g.

```cpp
    // in main.cpp
    qputenv("QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ", QString("1").toUtf8());
```

Here's the `XMLHttpRequest` code snippet:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Frame { 
        width: parent.width
        TextArea {
            width: parent.width
            wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
            TextLoader {
                url: "messages.txt"
            }
        }
    }
}

// TextLoader.qml
import QtQuick
Item {
    id: textLoader
    property var target: parent
    property string property: "text"
    property string url
    onUrlChanged: Qt.callLater(load)
    function load() {
        if (!url) return;
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url); 
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;
            if (xhr.status !== 0 && (xhr.status < 200 || xhr.status >= 400)) return;
            target[property] = xhr.responseText;
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
    Component.onCompleted: Qt.callLater(load)
}

// messages.txt
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris scelerisque augue non magna consectetur pretium quis lobortis mi. Sed fermentum, turpis at molestie imperdiet, odio magna elementum libero, quis posuere lorem risus in libero. Nunc ullamcorper massa eget condimentum venenatis. Donec eget tempus leo, id gravida sem. Duis eget libero id lorem fringilla accumsan dictum sed purus. Pellentesque tristique velit at quam pharetra, in porta tortor hendrerit. In tristique imperdiet velit, ac hendrerit metus sagittis a. Fusce suscipit tellus volutpat, accumsan metus non, tempus sem.
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)